# How to stop AudioSystem while exiting JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jframe, javasound

I'm making a game and I added music to it. Problem is when I close my game, music is still playing.

Script for playing music:

```
try {
        clip1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        try {
            clip1.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(music));
        } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!Settings.Music) {

            return;
        }
        clip1.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Script for looping music:

```
public static void tick() {

    if (clip1.isRunning()) {

        if (!Settings.Music) {

            clip1.stop();
            // this makes music stop when player changes settings 
        }
    }
    
    if (Settings.Music) {
        if (!clip1.isRunning()) {

            playMusic(Game.music1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a `WindowListener`/`WindowStateListener` which allows you to register for events like on close, iconified etc. of the `JFrame`. Inside there you will of course pause, or start the audio.

You can read more here on [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html):

`WindowStateListener` example (probably the simplest and is not as verbose and allows you to compare previous and new state, there are many other [WindowEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html) options to check for):

```
frame.addWindowStateListener((WindowEvent e) -> {
     if (e.getNewState() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED 
        || e.getNewState() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_ICONIFIED) {
        // TODO stop the audio when window is closed or iconified (minimzed)
     }
 });
```

`WindowListener` example ( a bit more verbose but here for completeness):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help mate